# How to convert Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.Array to an array of double?

Tags: c#, json, tcp

I have a Newtonsoft.Linq.Json.Array object which I obtained after running a camera and the string is received to my laptop via TCP/IP. The code which is used is shown below:

```
public async void ReadDataAsync(TcpClient mClient)
{
    try
    {
        StreamReader clientStreamReader = new StreamReader(mClient.GetStream());

        char [] buff = new char[1024];
        int readByCount = 0;            

        while (true)
        {
            readByCount = await clientStreamReader.ReadAsync(buff, 0, buff.Length);

            Directory.CreateDirectory("Camera o3D1");

            if (readByCount <= 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Disconnected from Server.");
                mClient.Close();
                break;
            }

            if (readByCount > 30)
            {
                var output = (new string(buff).TrimEnd('\u0000'));
                Console.WriteLine(output);                    

                Console.WriteLine(output.GetType());
                var output1 = output.Split(new[] { ";;" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(s => s.Split(';')).ToArray();

                JToken jsonParsed = JToken.FromObject(output1);
                Console.WriteLine(jsonParsed);
                Console.WriteLine(jsonParsed.GetType());
            }


                //File.WriteAllLines("Camera o3D1/file.json", jsonParsed);
                //File.AppendAllText("Camera o3D1/file.json", type);                

            Array.Clear(buff, 0, buff.Length);
        }

    }
    catch (Exception excp)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(excp.ToString());
    }
}
```

The output I received is:

```
 [
  [
    "17.623665",
    "87.380157",
    "51.530350",
    "121.286850",
    "+0.480"
  ],
  [
    "89.199364",
    "47.660252",
    "123.106056",
    "81.566940",
    "+0.521"
  ],
  [
    "\r\n"
  ]
]
```

Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray

I want to convert it into an array of double so that if I used `jsonparsed[0]`, I should get

```
[
    "17.62",
    "87.38",
    "51.53",
    "121.28",
    "+0.48"
 ]
```

and `jsonparsed[0][0]`, I should get 17.62 and everything in double. 
Does anyone of you have any idea how to do this?

Comment: Integer have not floating point

Comment: Thanks, I meant double. I changed the post asking to change into array of double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
   var input = $"[[\"17.623665\",\"87.380157\",\"51.530350\",\"121.286850\",\"+0.480\"],[\"89.199364\",\"47.660252\",\"123.106056\",\"81.566940\",\"+0.521\"]]";

            var jarray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(input);
            foreach (var arrayItem in jarray)
            {
                var innerArray = arrayItem.ToObject<double[]>();

                foreach (var item in innerArray)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item);
                }

            }
```

You would have to filter out the last empty item first:

```
  [
    "\r\n"
  ]
```

"\r\n" does not deserialize to a double..

Comment: It works, Can you tell me how to filter out  [ "\r\n"]

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems you have to solve:

- The data is not a flat array. Instead it is an array of arrays of doubles.
- Some of you values are not valid double values and you have to decide what should happen with them.

So lets first solve the most inner problem, which would be the conversion of the values to doubles. Due to the fact, that you are using Newtonsoft you can write your own converter and provide that to the serializer:

```
public class SpecialDoubleConverter : JsonConverter<double>
{
    public override double ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, double existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var rawValue = (string)reader.Value;

        // Decide what should be returned if the value can not be read as double
        // e.g. return some magic value like -17, double.NaN, 0, double.Epsilon, etc.
        return double.TryParse(rawValue, out double result)
            ? result
            : -17;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, double value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // Writing a double into a json string is the same as the default.
        writer.WriteValue(value.ToString());
    }
}
```

If you use this serializer you could get a nested array by this call:

```
var jsonParsed = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<double>>>(output1, new SpecialDoubleConverter());
```

Now we need to flatten this nested list, which can be achieved by using LINQ:

```
var doubleValues = jsonParsed.SelectMany(list => list).ToList();
```